# Install Project 2019 and Microsoft 365 on the same machine

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-project

I have Microsoft 365 - Personal x64 version 2109 installed.

I also need to install Project 2019 VL x64 which is provided by my company.

According to [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/install-different-office-visio-and-project-versions-on-the-same-computer), this scenario is supported, but I get this message when the setup runs: "To install this product, first uninstall the following product(s) and try again. Microsoft 365 - en-us".

What I'm missing?

Comment: Are both of these products the same type of install i.e Click-to-Run or MSI? You can [edit] your question to include this vital information.

Comment: Try to install the 32-bit version of Project 2019.

Comment: I suspect the problem is your attempting to mix Microsoft 365 Personal subscription with a volume license installation of Project 2019.  Which is not supported.  "For Office 365, Microsoft 365, Office LTSC 2021, and Office 2019 products, all products installed on the computer must be using the same update channel." - In other words `Project 2019 VL` is using the PerpetualVL2019 update channel while `Office 365` is using the Current channel.

Comment: [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/935064/deploying-office-365-proplus-and-project-2019-volume-licensing) confirms my theory.

Comment: Which version of Microsoft 365 apps are you using? If possible, you can try to uninstall Microsoft 365 apps and then install Project first and then install Microsoft 365.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and least fiddly answer is to uninstall Office 365, install Project 2019, then re-install Office 365.

The other way is to edit the config.xml you generate for installing Project 2019 and change the 'channel' part of the xml to match the one being used for Office 365.  I think the default would be Channel="broad".  Others are 'current' and 'monthly' (or were last time I looked into this).

Check this useful article:
https://oregonstate.teamdynamix.com/TDClient/1935/Portal/KB/ArticleDet?ID=105632